# Problem with gnuplot and lualatex

Tags: luatex, gnuplot

I have a pretty complicated graph to plot from coordinates.A friend from here adviced me to use gnuplot and also helped me with the code which is the following...

```
\documentclass[border= 5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={bluered}{rgb255(0cm)=(0,0,180); rgb255(1cm)=(0,255,255);rgb255(2cm)=(100,255,0);rgb255(3cm)=(255,255,0); rgb255(4cm)=(255,0,0); rgb255(5cm)=(128,0,0)}} 
\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
1   1   70
2   1   48
3   1   41  
4   1   70
5  1   68
6   1   82
7   1   38
8   1   47
9   1   35
10  1   66
11  1   53
12  1   78
1   2   91
2   2   43
3   2   68
4   2   90
5  2   66
6   2   55
7   2   66
8   2   46
9   2   25
10  2   38
11  2   50
12  2   58
1   3   60
2   3   68
3   3   39
4   3   65
5  3   59
6   3   69
7   3   72
8   3   62
9   3   94
10  3   36
11  3   33
12  3   39
1   4   48
2   4   80
3   4   68
4   4   66
5  4   59
6   4   63
7   4   93
8   4   63
9   4   30
10  4   52
11  4   60
12  4   14
1  5  74
2  5  84
3  5  86
4  5  39
5  5  76
6  5  51
7  5  43
8  5  55
9  5  37
10  5  60
11  5  49
12  5  42
1  6  74
2  6  51
3  6  62
4  6  45
5  6  69
6  6  58
7  6  73
8  6  50
9  6  58
10  6  50
11  6  64
12  6  42
1  7  60
2  7  57
3  7  80
4  7  59
5  7  48
6  7  60
7  7  69
8  7  56
9  7  67
10  7  51
11  7  32
12  7  57
1  8  43
2  8  88
3  8  64
4  8  62
5  8  56
6  8  65
7  8  34
8  8  44
9  8  80
10  8  52
11  8  66
12  8  42
1  9  86
2  9  61
3  9  68
4  9  71
5  9  61
6  9  51
7  9  62
8  9  52
9  9  49
10  9  62
11  9  46
12  9  27
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12},xticklabels={FRO,NOM,FER,EMM,COR,MOU,OZO,DRH,ELI,ANT,ARI,PAV},xmin=0,xmax=13,xlabel=Players,ylabel=Rounds,zlabel=Points Per Round,colormap/bluered,width=30cm,height=20cm,point meta min=30, point meta max=85]
 \addplot3 [surf] gnuplot [raw gnuplot] {
    set dgrid3d 52,52 spline;
    splot 'data.txt';       
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This results to the following pic which is quite impressive BUT...

[image]

Ι wanted something more smooth...so I set dgrid3d 100,100 spline;
This did not work because over 52 the tex capacity is exceeded...
So by searching I found that lualatex does not have the same restrictions!
So I tried the same code with lualatex...

But I got the next message:

[image]

So if anyone can help me use gnuplot with lualatex I would be grateful!
Thanks in advance!
A

Comment: Did you compile the file using `lualatex --shell-escape <filename>`, as suggested by the error message?

Comment: Well, I had the shell-escape option when compiling with latex... I do not know how to use this option in lualatex. What should I do?

Comment: It looks like you are using TeXShop.  The standard LuaTeX engine does not enable the `shell-escape` option.  I would recommend making a new engine with the option added. In `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines` you'll find the `LuaLaTeX.engine`.  Make a copy of it can call it `LuaLaTeX-shell.engine`.  Edit this file and add the `--shell-escape` to the `lualatex` line in the Engine. Restart TeXShop and then the engine should appear in the pulldown menu.

Comment: It appeared right in the pulldown menu... so I chose it to compile the code but I received again the same error message.In the engine I wrote this:  #!/bin/tcsh

set path= ($path /usr/texbin /usr/local/bin)
lualatex --shell-escape-file-line-error -synctex=1 "$1"

Comment: @Ariscampis Open the `.engine` file in TeXShop and make sure that the options are correctly introduced with --. When I opened the engine file by double clicking it, it opened in TextEdit and changed the -- to –. Your file compiles without error for me with the new values. Also, you need a space between each of the options.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you are using TeXShop. The standard LuaTeX engine does not enable the shell-escape option. I would recommend making a new engine with the option added. In `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines` you'll find the `LuaLaTeX.engine`. Make a copy of it can call it `LuaLaTeX-shell.engine`. Edit this file in TeXShop and add the `--shell-escape` to the `lualatex` line in the Engine.

The line should read:

```
lualatex --shell-escape --file-line-error --synctex=1 "$1"
```

Restart TeXShop and then the engine should appear in the pulldown menu. Use this engine to compile your LuaTeX+GNUplot files.

Comment: It worked perfectly!!! Thank you so much!!! Strangely I had to write: lualatex -shell-escape -file-line-error -synctex=1 "$1".Thanks again!